# My nav doesnt responsive and logo is higher than nav

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I`m make a navigation like in that psd file:

```
https://imgur.com/a/OEbJDAX
```

But in my html/css code this nav looks like that:

```
https://imgur.com/a/1OlW3eW
```

You can see that logo is highter than navigation and this navigation doesnt make responsive if I will reduce the size

I tried to change container, made a flex in css. But it did not help.

HTML:

```
   <header>
        <div class="container">
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h2 class="logo">NEWPROVIDENCE</h2>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <a href="#" class="apple"><i class="fab fa-apple fa-1x"></i>Get app</a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </header>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    background: url('../img/bg-header.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

#main-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2rem;
}

#main-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
}

#main-nav ul li a {
    padding: 0.75rem;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 0.25rem;
    color: #26272d;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #bebebf;
}


.apple {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #267df4;

}

.apple i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code here instead of outside source. Use a code snippet and save us some work to copy your code to a reply. ;)

Comment: sorry, i changed my topic

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you need the elements on either side of logo to stay central vertically as the logo grows or shrinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your logo and all your nav links inside 1 `ul` list instead of using 2 lists. Something like this:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: url('../img/bg-header.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

#main-nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  color: #26272d;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #bebebf;
}

.apple {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #267df4;
}

.apple i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="main-nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="logo">
          <h2>NEWPROVIDENCE</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <a href="#" class="apple"><i class="fab fa-apple fa-1x"></i>Get app</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

For the **responsive** part, try using some media queries. I suggest you add your logo to the top of the list and show only top logo on mobile and middle logo on wide screens. For example:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: url('../img/bg-header.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

#main-nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  color: #26272d;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #bebebf;
}

.apple {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #267df4;
}

.apple i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* ADDED CSS */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .logo.mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .logo.desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.menu li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="main-nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="logo mobile hidden">
          <h2>NEWPROVIDENCE</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="logo desktop">
          <h2>NEWPROVIDENCE</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <a href="#" class="apple"><i class="fab fa-apple fa-1x"></i>Get app</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

And finally, to get the menu links nicely to the left and right of the screen on desktop devices, while keeping the logo centered, you could use a css grid for your menu. See this example as a result:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: url('../img/bg-header.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2rem;
}


/* Changed to grid */

#main-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto) 1fr repeat(3, auto);
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/**/

#main-nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  color: #26272d;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #bebebf;
}

.apple {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #267df4;
}

.apple i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* ADDED CSS */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .logo.mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .logo.desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  #main-nav ul {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
  ul.menu li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="main-nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="logo mobile hidden">
          <h2>NEWPROVIDENCE</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="logo desktop">
          <h2>NEWPROVIDENCE</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <a href="#" class="apple"><i class="fab fa-apple fa-1x"></i>Get app</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: in your example navigation does not locate in the center of page

Comment: sorry i missed. between li and h2 doest not any spaces. How can i add that?

Comment: please see revised answer snippet :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

At  tag just give style="height:something in percentage example :20 percent ; width :in some percent